# jquery autocomplete open function getting called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that attaches an autocomplete to any textbox I pass into it. As you can see, in the open function, towards the end, I fill in the word for the user and select the autofilled part so that they can delete it by pressing the delete key. The problem I am having is that when I delete the autofilled/autoselected part by pressing delete, the open function runs again for some reason and autofills the word again. This behavior only happens once. If I go ahead and delete the autofilled text for a second time, the textbox stays that way.

```
function attachAutoComplete(id, webMethod) {
    $("#" + id).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: webMethod,
                data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return { value: item }
                    }))
                }
            });
        },
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () { }
        },
        minLength: 2,
        open: function () {
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('width', '169px');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', '10000');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('list-style-type', 'none');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('border-width', '1px');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('border-color', '#b6b6b6');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('border-style', 'solid');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('background-color', '#fff');
            $('.ui-autocomplete').css('padding', '0px');
            $('.ui-menu-item').css('cursor', 'pointer');
            var input = $(this),
                firstElementText = input.data("ui-autocomplete").menu.element[0].children[0].textContent,
                original = input.val();
            input.val(firstElementText);
            input[0].selectionStart = original.length;
            input[0].selectionEnd = firstElementText.length;
        },
        close: function () {
            var input = $(this);
            var firstThreeLetters = input[0].id.substring(0, 3);            
            if (firstThreeLetters == "SNP") {
                GetVariantsGene(input);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

update: The open function only runs again if the last character that the user entered is a letter. If the last character is a number, it does not run again.

Comment: You showed us the open function, but not where it is called. Obviously the function works, what is broken is where it is called and the conditions in which it is called.

Comment: ?? JQuery is supposed to take care of that. When you declare $(id).autocomplete{}, it takes care of calling the optional functions contained in autocomplete for you...

Comment: But it has to be activated in some sort of keypress event logic or called somewhere else. You can't debug it unless you show a possibility of where the bug happens.

Comment: it is activated when the menu opens. I didn't write any code to call it...